# How to post two different events to the same Contiki process?

Tags: contiki, contiki-process

I have two Contiki processes with one process, `master`, posting two different events to a second process, `send`. The first event sent is `PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE` and the second event is `PROCESS_EVENT_MSG`.

I am posting these events sequentially, one after another, from the process called `main`.

The complete code is:

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "lib/list.h"
#include "lib/memb.h"
#include "lib/random.h"
#include "net/rime/rime.h"

#include<stdio.h>

PROCESS(master, "master_DGHS"); 
PROCESS(send, "master_DGHS"); 

AUTOSTART_PROCESSES( &master, &send);

PROCESS_THREAD(master, ev, data)
{
    PROCESS_BEGIN();

    process_post(&send, PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE, NULL);
    process_post(&send, PROCESS_EVENT_MSG, NULL);

    PROCESS_END();
}


PROCESS_THREAD(send, ev, data)
{
    static struct etimer et;

    PROCESS_BEGIN();

    while(1)
    {
        PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT(); 
        if(ev == PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE)
        {
            printf("PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE\n");
            etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND );
            PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));

        }else
        if(ev == PROCESS_EVENT_MSG)
        {
            printf("PROCESS_EVENT_MSG\n");
            etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND  );
            PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
        }

    }
    PROCESS_END();
 }
```

The problem is that the second process `send` sees the first event (it prints `PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE`), but it doesn't see the second event (it does not print `PROCESS_EVENT_MSG`).

In other words, the second event gets lost. However if I remove the source line

```
PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
```

the  second process `send` sees both events (both `PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE` and `PROCESS_EVENT_MSG` are printed). So, adding this source line causes the second event, `PROCESS_EVENT_MSG`, to be ignored or discarded.

Why does adding this source line result in the second event getting lost?

Comment: This code is correct. You need to post more details (the `send` process code would help). The only thing I can think of `PROCESS_CONF_NUMEVENTS` being defined to a small number and the event buffer overflowing, which would lead to loss of events.

Comment: The problem appears when I add PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et)) in each event (as shown in the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL` [consumes all events](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Documentation:-Processes-and-events) until the loop's condition becomes true.

> By calling PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL() in the area separated by the
>   PROCESS_BEGIN() and PROCESS_END() calls, one can yield control to the
>   scheduler, and only resume execution when an event is delivered. A
>   condition is given as an argument to PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(), and
>   this condition must be fulfilled for the processes to continue
>   execution after the call to PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(). If the
>   condition is not fulfilled, the process yields control back to the OS
>   until a new event is delivered.

This is the sequence of actions in your example:

1. The `send` process gets `PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE` event.
2. The process executes the first `printf`, sets up a timer, and enters `PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));`
3. The `send` process gets `PROCESS_EVENT_MSG` event immediately after.
4. The process is still in the `WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL` loop and discards the second event, because the timer is not expired yet.
5. The timer expires and the `send` process gets `PROCESS_EVENT_TIMER` event.
6. The process exits the wait loop.

So, the second event is received by the process, but not acted upon, since the process is waiting for another event. Hope that now you understand why removing the `WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL` macro solves this issue.